# Does this function appear in theory of modular forms?

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, theta-functions

Does the following function $\phi(q,z)$ appear in theory of modular forms
$$
\phi(q,z):=\prod_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(1+q^nz)
$$
for $(q,z)$ in some domain in $\mathbb{C}^2$? 
Any reference will be appreciated.

Comment: I doubt it since this product does not converge. On the other hand for $0<|q|<1$ the product $$\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}(1+q^{2k+1}z)(1+q^{2k+1}z^{-1})$$ is a famous theta function.